# Limit of a constant function ? Given $a_n = c $ for all $n \in N$. How about $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

I hope my question is not too dumb.

Given a real sequence $a_n$, it is always equal to some constant c for any positive integer number. For example,$a_n = \frac{1}{n^2+1}(n^2+1) = 1,\forall n\in N$.

My question:

1. Is $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } a_n = c$?
2. Maybe my following up question is that Is $a_n$ still well defined at $n=\infty$? Any counterexample?

Comment: Yes, the limit is $c$. And $a_n$ is well defined for every positive integer $n$.

Comment: $\forall n, ||a_n - c|| = 0$, so the answer to 1 is yes ; for 2, what do you mean by "well defined at $\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For any $\varepsilon > 0$, $|a_n - c| < \varepsilon$ for all $n$. Thus, by definition, $\lim a_n = c$.
2. $n = \infty$ doesn't make sense because $\infty$ is not a natural number. If you were going to make a definition you would probably want to define $a_\infty = \lim a_n$ in which case if $a_n = c$ then $a_\infty = c$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!.